# What LEGO Power Functions parts do I need to make an RC car?

Tags: technic, power-functions, remote-control

I'd like to make a remote control car with steering and forward/back functionality.

Looking at the [LEGO Power Functions parts](http://shop.lego.com/en-NZ/Power-Functions-ByCategory) I'm assuming I need the following:

1. A battery box (8881 or 8878)
2. A motor for drive (8883, 888003, 7772)
3. A servo for the steering (88004)
4. A IR receiver (8884)
5. A IR remote (8885)
6. Some Extension Cables? (8871, 8886)

But I'm not sure how the IR remote is configured to control the motor/servo or whether I need an IR receiver (8884) per motor/servo, or whether I'm missing another part.

What Power Functions parts do I need to make a LEGO remote control car?

Comment: The servo is not mandatory, you can use a standard motor with elastics for the steering: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQ5ug1CwRa8 (warning: aggressive music)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumptions appear to be mostly correct. Just for clarity, these are the minimum parts required:

1. A battery box
2. A motor for driving
3. A motor for steering (unless you want to try a [steer-on-reverse single motor design](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/how-to-build-a-steerable-remote-controlled-vehicle-with-just-1-motor/7365))
4. An IR receiver (these can support two motors each)
5. An IR remote

Extension cables and/or lights are optional depending on the design of your vehicle.